# "Medusa"-type book set around Sedona, AZ

Tags: story-identification

Some years ago, I read a sci-fi novel set in motion by the discovery of a 19th century Apache man who had been turned to stone in a cave near Sedona, AZ. Elements I recall of it are that there was an alternate dimension accessible through that cave and there being a threat to Earth.